# Specifying the subtype of a Generic in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, variance

Consider the following example, which should print 8. Why does the `A.Value + B.Value` thinks that `B.Value` should be a string? How do I fix it?

```
object Catano extends App {
  val const3 = new Constant(3)
  val const5 = new Constant(5)

  val block = new Arithmetic(const3.Result, const5.Result)

  println(block.Sum.Value)
}

class Block

class Arithmetic[T: Numeric](val A: Connector[T], val B: Connector[T]) extends Block {
  def Sum = new Connector({ A.Value + B.Value })
}

class Constant[T](x: T) extends Block {
  def Result = new Connector({ x })
}

class Connector[T](f: => T) {
  def Value: T = f
}
```

For type-safety reasons, the following should fail with a Type exception:

```
  val const3 = new Constant("ping")
  val const5 = new Constant("pong")

  val block = new Arithmetic(const3.Result, const5.Result)
```

Comment: This does print 8 for me, provided I import `scala.math.Numeric.Implicits_` Also, your capitalization is distinctly C#-ish. Member `val`s and `def`s generally start with a lower case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced with just:

```
class C[T: Numeric] {def add(a: T, b: T) = a+b }
error: type mismatch;
found   : T
required: String
```

What is happening there : in scala as in java, you can do String + anything, and also anything + String. As, unlike in java, pperators are just normal method calls, that seems to imply there is a corresponding + method on each type. Of course, it is not so, as java types have no such method. What we have is `implicit def any2StringAdd(x: Any)` in `Predef`, which makes this `+` available by implicit conversion. In your code, this is the only + available, which is why it complains `B.Value` is not a `String`.

Now why is the intended `+` not available? `T:Numeric` requires that there is a `Numeric[T]` value in implicit scope. It says nothing about what type T should be, and what methods are available on `T`. This `Numeric[T]` instance has a `def plus(x: T, y: T): T` method. That alone does not make `+` available on T. You can call plus directly, but this is not covenient. Fortunately, a `+` delegating to `plus` can be added by implicit conversion (just like the `+(String)` was in `Predef`), provided you put some implicits in scope with :

```
import Numeric.Implicits._
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Arithmetic[ T <: Int] (val A: Connector[T], val B: Connector[T]) extends Block {
  def Sum = new Connector({ A.Value + B.Value })
}
```

Numeric doesn't have a `+` function

Comment: That is a simple and nice example of how to solve my problem :-)

Comment: What's the point of T <: Int, given that Int cannot be subclassed?

Comment: Yes... True... What would be the correct way of specifying Int, and only Int?